# Once patch is applied by linux maintainer, when and in which linux git branch I can see my patch?

Tags: linux, git, linux-kernel, open-source, linux-device-driver

I submit my patch to lkml community and its been applied by the maintainer yesterday, but I couldn't see my patch in linux-next.git yet.
I want to know if it is the correct branch to see my patch ? 
if 'no' where can I see ?
If 'yes' do I need to wait for some more time ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stephen Rothwell who takes care of linux-next is currently on holiday. So your patch will appear there when he gets back. Else, you can find were is the tree for the particular subsystem your patch has been applied to in `MAINTAINERS`, look for `T:` lines.